# Python making turtle graphic by using list colors

Tags: python, list, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make squares with change color each time when I click. but when I run this, it only fills out red color. How can I change color each times?

```
import turtle
t= turtle.Turtle()
s=turtle.Screen()
colors = ["red","orange","yellow","green","blue","indigo","purple"]
n=0

def square(x,y):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x,y)
    t.pendown()
    t.color(colors[n])
    t.begin_fill()   
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(90)
        t.lt(90)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()
if s.onscreenclick(square) == True:
    n+=1
```

Comment: at least copy code text so we don't have to retype it :)

Comment: i printed out code plz help

Comment: Try to change `t.color()` inside `if` statement instead of using global variable `n`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a call to `s.mainloop()`. And if you want `n` to change with each click, declare it as global within the `square()` function, and increment it after you finish drawing. Don't forget to reset `n` to zero if it gets larger than `len(colors)`.

The call to `s.onscreenclick()` is telling the turtle 'how to handle a click' (by calling `square()` in this case), so you don't need to put into an `if` statement.

```
import turtle
t= turtle.Turtle()
s=turtle.Screen()
colors = ["red","orange","yellow","green","blue","indigo","purple"]
n=0

def square(x,y): # draw a square at (x,y)
    global n # use the global variable n
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x,y)
    t.pendown()
    t.color(colors[n])
    t.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(90)
        t.lt(90)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()
    n = (n+1) % len(colors) # change the colour after each square

s.onscreenclick(square) # whenever there's a click, call square()

s.mainloop() # start looping
```

Finally, be sure to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), as it's your first time on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a global counter and modulus operation, I prefer to use `cycle()` from itertools which simply keeps repeating the list:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from itertools import cycle

colors = cycle(["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "purple"])

def square(x, y):
    screen.onscreenclick(None)  # disable handler inside handler

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.color(next(colors))

    turtle.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(75)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

    turtle.penup()

    screen.onscreenclick(square)

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

screen.onscreenclick(square)

screen.mainloop()
```

Also note that I disabled the  `onscreenclick()` handler inside the implementation of the handler so the user can't click while the previous square is still being drawn as that leads to messy results.